# how to acquire data from Flash chart on website pages

Tags: html, flash, swfobject

We have service from others, however they only offer chart on a old FLASH website pages. it will update daily data in the FLASH chart. i need to read the data and input into a sheet. and it is a daily job. besides, latest Chrome doesn't support FLASH anymore. i think there is a sollution to have the data only. i reviewed the website pages.

swfobject.embedSWF data-file chart

```
        </table>
        <div style="float: right; width: 75%; margin-right: 5px;">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="ofc"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("/WebResource.axd?d=RANDOMCHARACTERSTRING&t=636791717427507377", "ofc", "750px", "400px","9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf",{"data-file":"%2fchart%2fdatafile%2fdata.aspx%3fbegindate%3d2023-01-01%26enddate%3d2023-12-31%26cityname%3d%25e6%259d%25ad%25e5%25b7%259e%252c%26typename%3d%25e7%2583%25ad%25e8%25bd%25a7%25e6%259d%25bf%25e5%258d%25b7%26quaParam%3d3.0%26n%3d2058395191","loading":"LOADING AND WAIT"});</script>
```

Is there any idea to have the data? and i can do it in MS EXCEL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGIEM.png).

Comment: Please consider elaborating on what this data is. The fact it was used by a **Flash** app tells us literally nothing.

Comment: @Organis There is a `"data-file":` mentioned on the last line. It's the most important detail but of course it's hidden away because its 2023 and not many will tell what they actually mean (in order to solve their problem) on S.O anymore. World is changing...

Comment: @AlexFang **(1)** You have to use the path in `data-file`. First thing is that it is **URL encoded** so you must [decode](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) it before usage, for example `%2fchart%2fdatafile%2fdata.aspx` when **decoded** becomes `/chart/datafile/data.aspx` (you replace %2F, %3F, %3D etc with correct characters for such codes). **(2)** is that ASPX script file supposed to exist on your website or the website of _"service from others"_? **(3)** Confirm if you are testing all this by using online server? localhost server? or just some HTML file in your hard drive folder?